# Failed to read auto-increment value from storage engine catalog_product_entity_varchar

Tags: magento2, database, catalog-product

Can't add a new product and get an error.

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1467 Failed to read auto-increment value from storage engine, query was: INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_entity_varchar` (`entity_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`,`value`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?)

Similar issue: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/21890

[image]

Please help us to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: Your fix seems to work for us with Magento 2.3.5p2 however it seems we are using a lot of attributes so our table 'catalog_product_entity_varchar' seems to be getting full. We are hitting a maximum. Is there a solution to increase the increment value to accept more id's? Cheers, Steve

Comment: Change table ID field type int(11) to Bigint(11)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this query on your database

```
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AUTO_INCREMENT = // last record's value_id+1 which is currently present in your table e.g if value_id is 5 than AUTO_INCREMENT = 6. If table is empty than put AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

Don't forget to create a backup of your DB first.